# What's the best way to allow users to match columns in source data to columns in a database?

Tags: vb.net, csv, data-binding, import, datatable

I'm working with source CSV files from various sources and have no control over the names of columns.

I want to give users a list of columns in the database and allow them to pick which columns in the source file should be used to populate them.

My first thought was to generate a list of labels for one set of columns and put a combobox next to each label with a list of the other set of columns but this allows me to select columns multiple times and it feels like there's a lot of repetition in the code.

```
    For Each col In ImportTable.Columns
        Dim l As New Label
        l.Name = "l" + col.columnname
        l.Text = col.columnname
        llabels.Add(l)
        Dim c As New ComboBox
        c.Width = 250
        c.Name = col.columnname
        Dim newlist As New List(Of String)
        newlist.Add("-IGNORE-")
        For Each pcol In AppDataSet.Patients.Columns
            If pcol.ToString = "IdColumn" Then Continue For
            newlist.Add(pcol.ToString)
        Next
        c.DataSource = newlist
        lcombos.Add(c)
    Next

    For i = 0 To llabels.Count - 1
        llabels(i).Location = New Point(20, 40 + i * 30)
        Me.Controls.Add(llabels(i))
        lcombos(i).Location = New Point(150, 40 + i * 30)
        Me.Controls.Add(lcombos(i))
    Next
```

How can I do this a better way and additionally what should I bear in mind considering the data import and telling it which values to put where as well as handling different datatypes when I import the rows from the source into my database? I'm using a DataSet bound to a SQLExpress database.

Comment: What you are doing will do the job just fine - have used the same technique many times. You could add a custom event handler as well that tracks the available columns, selected columns, and adjusts the values in the combo boxes dynamically.

Comment: Its pretty easy to implement the means to exclude previous sections from subsequent ones.  You could use a `UserControl` for the UI to minimize redundancy (and leaks)